# What is the difference between `:limit` and `limit:`?

Tags: ruby, literals

What is the difference between `:limit` and `limit:`? I am assuming the first is the method for limiting entry size in Ruby on Rails. What is the second for? I also don't know what is the significance of putting column `n` on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an issue with hash notation.

Ruby 1.8 and prior use a style like this:

```
method(:limit => 10)
```

Ruby 1.9 and more recent have a new style that looks like:

```
method(limit: 10)
```

The new notation is a lot more like that in other languages like Python and JavaScript. They are functionally identical, though, as you can check with `irb` where it always shows in conventional notation:

```
{ test: 'value' }
# => { :test => 'value' }
```

As to your question as to what `limit` means, it really depends on what method you're passing this in to. In the context of a schema definition it can limit the size of a field:

```
t.string limit: 1024
```

If it's in the context of a query it might limit the number of results returned. Each method has their own interpretation so you'll need to consult the documentation on each method you encounter.

Answer (score 0):

`:limit` is a value of type symbol. You can see more about symbols on Ruby docs. http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Symbol.html

`limit:` is a syntactic sugar and can be used only as a hash key when this key is a symbol. Example: `{ :limit => 10 }` is the traditional way. After Ruby 1.9.3 you can rewrite that like `{ limit: 10 }`

Comment: thanks ,  i thought it was not the same .

Answer (score -1):

Variables that have a colon `:` before their name denounces that they are symbols (unique identifier) and this means that it is possible to do the following:

```
symbol = :limit
```

using the colon after the name is usually meant to indicate a hash key, such as the following:

```
hash = { limit: 5 }
puts hash[:limit] # returns 5
```

The confusion often ensues when working with older versions of ruby, where hashes are written as follows:

```
hash = { :limit => 5 }
puts hash[:limit] # returns 5
```

Which has the same exact meaning as the above statement.

Comment: your examples don't work

Comment: `:limit = 5` => `SyntaxError: (irb):21: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting end-of-input`

Comment: `puts :limit` => `limit`

Comment: `hash = { limit: 5 }; hash.limit` => `NoMethodError: undefined method `limit' for {:limit=>5}:Hash`

Comment: `hash = { :limit => 5 }; puts hash.limit` => `NoMethodError: undefined method `limit' for {:limit=>5}:Hash`